# Average difference between dates in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have a series of datetime objects and would like to calculate the average delta between them.

For example, if the input was `(2008-10-01 12:15:00, 2008-10-01 12:25:00, 2008-10-01 12:35:00)`, then the average delta would be exactly 00:10:00, or 10 minutes.

Any suggestions on how to calculate this using Python?

Comment: We can be more helpful if you post your code.

Comment: It's not even clear what is sought here - average pairwise delta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract each successive date from the one prior (resulting in a timedelta object which represents the difference in days, seconds).  You can then average the timedelta objects to find your answer.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm trying to do. The averaging seems to be causing an issue; probably a Python mistake on my part. Ideas?

Answer (score 13):

As far as algorithms go, that's an easy one.  Just find the max and min datetimes, take the difference, and divide by the number of datetimes you looked at.

If you have an array a of datetimes, you can do:

```
mx = max(a)
mn = min(a)
avg = (mx-mn)/(len(a)-1)
```

to get back the average difference.

EDIT:  fixed the off-by-one error

Comment: Shouldn't it be (len(c) - 1)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (len(a) - 1)?  - since the other references seems to be to 'a' and not 'c'...

Comment: Can you divide timedelta objects?

Comment: Yep, it appears to be doing fine with the division here.

Comment: it will give median, not average.

Comment: @Evgeny No, median would be the timedelta in the middle of the list of sorted timedeltas (or the average of the two in the middle if the number of timedeltas is even). e.g. for a list of values `[1, 3, 19, 27, 28, 33, 34]`, the average of the differences is 5.5 while the median of the differences is 3.5.

Comment: @JAB it's a matter of definitions. The way I see it average is sum(a)/len(a), and median average between max and min. What op wants is not very clear. I got here by searching how to calculate average datetime. What is average delta - average pairwise or average in sequence?

Comment: @Evgeny No it's not. Please brush up your knowledge on what a [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is.

Comment: @JAB, ok, I see now, thanks. He wants sequential deltas and the formula is right:).

Comment: very clever! Took me a bit to see why. if you line up the dates sequentially and take the deltas, whatever you do you're going from the first date to the last date in that many steps..

Answer (score 3):

Say `a` is your list

```
sumdeltas = timedelta(seconds=0)
i = 1
while i < len(a):
    sumdeltas += a[i-1] - a[i]
    i = i + 1

avg_delta = sumdeltas / (len(a) - 1)
```

This will indeed average your deltas together.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be throwing out the 20 minute delta between times 1 and 3 in your example, I'd say you should just sort the list of datetimes, add up the deltas between adjacent times, then divide by n-1.

Do you have any code you can share with us, so we can help you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

small clarification

```
from datetime import timedelta

def avg(a):
    numdeltas = len(a) - 1
    sumdeltas = timedelta(seconds=0)

    i = 1
    while i < len(a):
        delta = abs(a[i] - a[i-1])
        try:
            sumdeltas += delta
        except:
            raise
        i += 1
    avg = sumdeltas / numdeltas
    return avg
```