# need the average from a list of timedelta objects

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have created a list of `timedelta` objects and i need to get the average of this list. when i try to do

```
return (sum(delta_list)/(len(delta_list)-1))
```

i get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I am new at working with python's `datetime` classes. I also would like to know how to get this average into a format like days: hours: mins: i don't need anything smaller than mins.

Comment: `Thanks in advanced.`. Don't thank in advance and forget to thank later. Learn to accept your answers.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted?  Does it get an error?  Please show the error you get?

Comment: I forgot to paste it,  I edited the question to include the error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`sum` wants a starting value, which is `0` by default, but `0` can't be added to a `timedelta` so you get the error.

You just have to give `sum` a `timedelta()` as the start value:

```
# this is the average
return sum(delta_list, timedelta()) / len(delta_list)
```

To print it out you can do this:

```
print str(some_delta)
```

If you want something customized you can get `some_delta.days` and `some_delta.seconds` but you have to calculate everything between.

Comment: @cferbs: Yes it's correct, to get the average you do `sum( .. ) / len( .. )`

Comment: In Python 3.3 make sure you use the '//' operator:

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `sum` adds all of the elements from the list to an initial value, which is by default `0` (an integer with value of zero). So to be able to use `sum` on a list of `timedelta`'s, you need to pass a `timedelta(0)` argument - `sum(delta_list, timedelta(0))`.

Secondly, why do you want to subtract one from the length of the list? If a list is of length 1 you'll get a `ZeroDivisionError`.

Having fixed the above you'll end up with a `timedelta` object being an average. How to convert that to a human-readable format I'm leaving for you as an exercise. The [datetime module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) should answer all of the possible questions.

Comment: I realized it was wrong. I got confused from other sample code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179716/average-difference-between-dates-in-python

Answer (score 3):

The [`sum()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) needs a start value to add all the items in the iterable to.  It defaults to `0` which is why you're getting the error about adding a `timedelta` to an `int`.

To fix this, just pass a `timedelta` object as the second argument to `sum`:

(Creating a `timedelta` with no arguments creates one corresponding to a zero time difference.)

Also, the mean of a set of items is usually the sum of items divided by the number of items so you don't need to subtract 1 from `len(delta_list)`.

These changes mean we can remove some of the brackets from your statement.

So this gives you:

```
return sum(delta_list,timedelta()) / len(delta_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `datetime.timedelta` object has attributes to access the days, microseconds, and seconds.  You can reference these easily, for example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> daybefore = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> dayminus2 = datetime.timedelta(days=2, minutes=60)
>>> daybefore.days
1
>>> dayminus2.days, dayminus2.seconds
(2, 3600)
```

To get minutes you're going to have to divide seconds by 60.