# Sum / Average an attribute of a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes, sum

Lets say I have class `C` which has attribute `a`.

What is the best way to get the sum of `a` from a list of `C` in Python?

---

I've tried the following code, but I know that's not the right way to do it:

```
for c in c_list:
    total += c.a
```

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
sum(c.a for c in c_list)
```

Comment: I like the simplicity, but it seems to take half again as long as (c1.A + c2.A + c3.A) for about 10 elements where c.A is a float.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for other measures than sum, e.g. mean/standard deviation, you can use NumPy and do:

```
mean = np.mean([c.a for c in c_list])
sd = np.std([c.a for c in c_list])
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar task, but mine involved summing a time duration as your attribute `c.a`.
Combining this with another question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006258/need-the-average-from-a-list-of-timedelta-objects), I came up with

```
sum((c.a for c in cList), timedelta())
```

Because, as mentioned in the link, `sum` needs a starting value.

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in `statistics` module:

```
import statistics

statistics.mean((o.val for o in my_objs))
```