# Get the total count of 1 field of a list of namedtuple objects

Tags: python, namedtuple

In Python, what is the easiest way to get the total count of one field from a set of named tuples?

In this example, I'm looking for the total count of `TestResults.failed`, which should be 4. It's doable with a `for` loop, but it feels like there could be a more efficient way.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

TestResults = namedtuple('TestResults', ['failed', 'attempted'])

test_results = [
    TestResults(0, 5),
    TestResults(3, 28),
    TestResults(1, 7)
]

failed_count = 0
for r in test_results:
    if hasattr(r, 'failed'):
        failed_count += r.failed

print(failed_count)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(i.failed for i in test_results)`?

Comment: And also why `hasattr(r, 'failed')` in your for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum / Average an attribute of a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879867/sum-average-an-attribute-of-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM - I was using `hasattr()` because in reality the named tuple comes from a 3rd party module, and I wanted to be sure I didn't get any errors if the field I was checking didn't exist. I've since inspected that module and can see that the field is required anyway, so the check is irrelevant and thus not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arbitrary objects, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with `0` as a default value, and use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/):

```
sum(getattr(res, 'failed', 0) for res in test_results)
```

Since you have namedtuples with no optional values, you can get the values directly using dot notation:

```
sum(res.failed for res in test_results)
```

If you have a namedtuple with an optional `'failed'` field, if the optional value is `0`, then the above should work, otherwise, if the optional value is `None`, you could use this to use `0` as a default value:

```
sum(res.failed or 0 for res in test_results)
```

Comment: Why would you need to use `getattr` when the objects are all a namedtuple guaranteed to have a `failed` attribute?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you're right, I was first assuming optional values, but even in that case the field would still exist.

Comment: @DjaouadNM - Thanks for you answer, your middle option works perfectly for my use case and saves some lines of code.