# How to add 'Timedelta' values in a python list

Tags: list, python-2.7, average, timedelta

I am trying to calculate the average of some time duration which I got from timestamp values .
So,I have a list having timedelta values and I want to add it and then calculate the average.
But, when I try to add it python gives me error as:

```
ValueError: cannot construct a TimeDelta without a value/unit or descriptive keywords (days,seconds....)
```

Here is the list I have:

```
[Timedelta('0 days 00:02:52'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:11'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:16'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:58'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:01'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:13'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:50'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:00'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:09'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:04'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:46'), Timedelta('201 days 00:12:05'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:08'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:47'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:01'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:46'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:46'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:15'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:03'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:04'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:04'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:02:47'), Timedelta('0 days 00:02:17'), Timedelta('0 days 00:03:00'), 
 Timedelta('0 days 00:03:03'), Timedelta('0 days 00:01:53')]
```

Could anyone please help me to understand what I am missing ?
Really appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006258/need-the-average-from-a-list-of-timedelta-objects

Comment: You forgot to post the code that attempts to do the adding that is causing the error.

Comment: what is this `Timedelta`?

Comment: @MSR974  Thank you so much .. the solution you shared solved my problem!!

Comment: @sudha11 glad it helped you =)